# Get the Git hash of the submodules using Python (Preferred pygit2)

Tags: python, git, git-submodules

I need to get the exact version (git hash) of all submodules of many git projects. In git command line I just type: `git submodule` and get what I want. I can't figure out how to access that information from Python. I'm currently using Pygit2, but I was only able to get list of submodules using `repo.listall_submodules()` and to lookup the name/url using `repo.lookup_submodule(submodule)`. I'm still missing the githash of the submodules.

Comment: Can't you just use `subprocess` and parse the output of `git submodule`?

Comment: I can, but there are many reasons to prefer a full Python solution. 1. The git output might change format in future versions. 2. It might be running on machine without git or with old Git version. 3. I want to learn and understand the pygit2 module.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the needed API, `git_submodule_head_id` was not exported to the Python bindings. I've created a PR to add it. https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/pull/817

Answer (score 0):

The PR mentioned by @Pagefault has been merged and the API is available in recent versions of pygit2. However, there is a little gotcha: `head_id` contains the hash stored in the parent repository. This would match the result of `git submodule --cached`.

If you have added commits to the submodule, this is not the same  as the hash displayed by a plain `git submodule` command (without `--cached`). To find the *current* hash, one has to get `HEAD` from the submodule.

So, for completeness, this is how a display similar to `git submodule` can be achieved:

```
import pygit2


repo = pygit2.Repository('/path/to/repository')

for name in repo.listall_submodules():
    sm = repo.lookup_submodule(name)
    # the hash recorded for the submodule is now available at sm.head_id
    sm_repo = sm.open()
    head = sm_repo.revparse_single("HEAD")
    print (f'{head.id} {name}')
```